# How do I load fixtures into a namespaced models table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

My model is `CWB::Account` (they are namespaced because I inherited this project and they used a few reserved words as model names)

I'm using minitest-spec-rails gem for testing and I'm getting this error -

`ActiveRecord::FxitureClassNotFound: No class attached to find.`

test/test-helper.rb

```
...

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  fixtures :all
end
...
```

test/controllers/sessions_controller_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class SessionsControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  before do
    account_one = Accounts(:account_one)
    register(account_one)
  end
...
```

test/fixtures/accounts.yml

```
account_one:
  id: 1
  name: testnameone
  email: one@gmail.com
  password_hash: passwordone
...
```

If I do this in test_helper.rb

```
set_fixture_class :accounts => 'CWB::Account'
fixtures :all
```

I get error - `StandardError no fixture named <CWB::Account:0x0000004bdf32> found for fixture set 'accounts'`

**EDIT**

Interesting update, if I put account.yml in fixtures/cwb/accounts.yml I get a bunch of errors about circular dependencies

but if I put it in fixture/CWB/accounts.yml (notice uppercase) I get an error saying

`undefined method accounts for ...`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1) put your fixture in /test/fixtures/cwb/accounts.yml

2) call cwb_accounts(:account_one) to get the record

```
require 'test_helper'

class SessionsControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  before do
    account_one = cwb_accounts(:account_one)
    register(account_one)
  end
...
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error and have combined everything I did to resolve it into this answer.

From [Brett Allred](https://stackoverflow.com/users/454421/brett-allred)'s answer, but loading just the specific named fixture:
(after putting the fixture in /test/fixtures/cwb/accounts.yml)

```
require 'test_helper'

class SessionsControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  fixtures: 'cwb/accounts'

  before do
    account_one = cwb_accounts(:account_one)
    ...
```

From [infused](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2456433/infused)'s answer, but assuming namespaced table names (as in a full engine):

```
set_fixture_class 'cwb/accounts' => CWB::Account
```

I'm actually using  rspec and namespaced table names. I think the only difference for the OP would be

```
set_fixture_class 'accounts' => CWB::Account
```

as his table is not namespaced (just the model)

Answer (score 1):

The class should be the actual class, not a string:

```
set_fixture_class :accounts => CWB::Account
```

Comment: is the table name `accounts`?